# Is their any way to create a list that accepts only two types in dart like typescript?

Tags: dart

I want to achieve something that makes me able to create a list that accepts two types.

if I want a list that accepts only String and a class type:

```dart
List<String | ClassType>
```

Comment: Nothing trivial.  You can build "union classes" with things like freezed, but it requires a build step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called union typing and it is [currently not supported in Dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1222). However, [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#union-types-and-sealed-classes) supports its own implementation of union types which is very similar to what you described.